# strtok error in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strtok

I have this small piece of code:

```
int* index=(int*)(sizeof(int)*NB);
while(i < NB){
    printf("i=%d, pch=%s\n", i, pch);
    if (strcmp(pch, SPLIT_PATTERN))
      i++;
    else
      index[k++]=i-1;
    pch = strtok(NULL, "-");
  }
```

and with this input:

```
file_content EN7FSQcL63NRUQHSBBRDtVUkobmStQbKdL2cR7gpoC5-X2rS1Cu2RCYaw0TiGdYUUtYuCTB5WlE9Y3SJNuiimQC-ajksldnalmcjlakjflksjoi-
NB = 2
SPLIT_PATTERN = ajksldnalmcjlakjflksjoi (the last part in file_content)
```

C give me the segmentation fault error.

```
i=0, pch=EN7FSQcL63NRUQHSBBRDtVUkobmStQbKdL2cR7gpoC5
i=1, pch=X2rS1Cu2RCYaw0TiGdYUUtYuCTB5WlE9Y3SJNuiimQC
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Please let me know where I do it wrong?

Comment: uh??? `int* index=(int*)(sizeof(int)*NB);` did you forget a `malloc()`?

Comment: What is the value of k?

Comment: You must provide the string to split with your first call to `strtok`. If you keep on splitting the same string, pass `NULL` on subsequent calls or pass a new string to start splitting that.

Comment: Where do you call `strtok` for first time?

Comment: G. Samaras, M Oehm: I did have it, just didn't past. @pmg's answer was right. THanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you meant to use:

```
int* index=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*NB);
```

instead of

```
int* index=(int*)(sizeof(int)*NB); // malloc is missing.
```

You should use

```
int* index=malloc(sizeof(int)*NB);
```

Having that additional `int*` before `malloc` is not a good idea. Checkout the answer in this SO post - [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Its 3 am here :(

Comment: maybe there should be a time-of-day delay for posting a question to SO, or perhaps just an "are you sure?"

Comment: It's a nice illustration of why casting malloc's return is a bad idea, although the reason could be spelled out a bit more for posterity.

Answer (score 1):

Possible errors with this code are:

```
int* index=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*NB);
while(i < NB){
    printf("i=%d, pch=%s\n", i, pch);
    if (strcmp(pch, SPLIT_PATTERN))
      i++;
    else
      index[k++]=i-1;
    pch = strtok(NULL, "-");
}
```

1)Incorrect value for `k`, maybe it's uninitialized, or it goes out of bounds?

2) `strtok` is called only with `NULL` as parameter. Here is a simple example of how this should work:

```
/* strtok example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str," ,.-");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

which gives output

```
Splitting string "- This, a sample string." into tokens:
This
a
sample
string
```

For more, read [strtok ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/).

Note that we do not cast what malloc returns. [Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

[EDIT]

However, your output implies that you are calling `strtok` before the `while` loop.